# Try to make checkbox checked by default on woocommerce product data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to make a checkbox checked by default when creating a new product in the WordPress dashboard.

[image]

I found the checkbox part of the code in the plugin, the original code is as follows:

```
woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
                    array(
                        'value'         => $proxy,
                        'id'            => '_auction_proxy',
                        'wrapper_class' => '',
                        'label'         => esc_html__( 'Proxy bidding?', 'wc_simple_auctions' ),
                        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Enable proxy bidding', 'wc_simple_auctions' ),
                        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
                    ), 
                );
```

I modified the code, and the modified code is as follows:

```
$checked = $post->get_value( '_auction_proxy' ) ? $checkout->get_value( '_auction_proxy' ) : 1;
                woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
                    array(
                        'value'         => $proxy,
                        'id'            => '_auction_proxy',
                        'wrapper_class' => '',
                        'label'         => esc_html__( 'Proxy bidding?', 'wc_simple_auctions' ),
                        'description'   => esc_html__( 'Enable proxy bidding', 'wc_simple_auctions' ),
                        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
                    ), $checked
                );
```

Then WordPress crash and showing critical error on the page.